# Is there a reason why the value of a wchar_t retrieved by mbtowc() is not the UNICODE value?

Tags: linux, solaris, i18n

If I convert the character 'ö' from a UTF-8 locale (where is is represented by the two octetts 0xC3 0xB6) to a `wchar_t`, I get a `wchar_t` value that is `0xF6`. This applies to Linux and Solaris.

If I convert the character 'ö' from a ISO-8859-1 locale (where is is represented by the single octett 0xF6) to a `wchar_t`, I get a `wchar_t` value of 0xF6 on Linux and a value of 0x30000076 on Solaris.

Does anybody know the reason and is able to explan the background?

BTW: since the i18n sourcecode from Solaris is shared by Sun/Oracle, IBM and HP, there is a big chance that this applies to AIX and HP-UX as well.

Comment: Quoting [The wchar_t mess](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/The-wchar_005ft-mess.html): "On Solaris and FreeBSD, the wchar_t encoding is locale dependent and undocumented. [...] As a consequence, it is better to use multibyte strings."

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on wide characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C/C++) also contains an interesting quote: "The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text."

Comment: Unfortunately the related GNU text is not 100% correct and does not explain the backgound. What I was not aware of is that you cannot compare the `wchar_t` result from a `mbtowc()` call with the character constant `'ö'` and this is not possible even when converting `'ö'` results in `0xF6` since the constant `'ö'` results in the signed value -10.

Comment: Have you used `setlocale (LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8")` (or similar) beforehand?

Comment: `mbtowc()` assumes the `C` locale if `setlocale()` was not called. The fact that there is different behavior in different locales should make it obvious that `setlocale()` has been called.